# How to go back to default ubuntu greeter?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, unity-greeter

I setup my PC from a Xubuntu iso file. After a while, I decided to install the `ubuntu-desktop` package to switch to Ubuntu. When I turn on my PC, the greeter I get is the same that came with Xubuntu. How do I setup the default Ubuntu greeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

If lightdm is installed do

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Comment: Becko might not have lightdm installed. If that's the case, dpkg-reconfigure won't help. In that case, install it using `sudo apt-get install lightdm`

Comment: @TSJNachos117 Thanks.  You're right.  Need to fully wakeup before answering :)

Comment: I already have `lightdm` installed. What do I do?

Comment: That didn't work. I'm still getting the xubuntu greeter.

Comment: I have tested many ways, and I think the best way is to reinstall Ubuntu, keep the DM that you have, or try to install GDM.  Sorry.  Also you might want to take a look at https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/247412

Comment: If the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure` doesn't work, try running `sudo apt-get install lightdm --reinstall`. That should reinstall lightdm.